# Subscript and Superscript format data uploaded in Excel not showing

Tags: asp.net, excel, file-upload, subscript, superscript

I want to import an excel sheet that contains data in subscript and superscript format. I want directly import the formula from Excel not by cropping as image. I am getting like this without any formating `(a+b)2=a2+b2+2ab`.
The application runs on the ASP.net framework and MS SQL database. Datatype for the column in SQL is `nvarchar`.

Appreciate if somebody can please help/guide me out of this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you view the Excel sheet and it looks like:

[image]

then what you are exporting is the string in the Formula Bar and not what you see in the cell.  You need to modify the export to tell the destination app to display superscripting.

For example, if the destination app interprets HTML, then you should export:

```
(a+b)<sup>2</sup>=a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>+2ab
```

*(its still a simple string, but the formatting instructions are part of the string)*

If the destination app needs rtf, then a different format needs to be exported.